# jQuery - why is attribute not being removed? .removeAttr

Tags: jquery

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/QyhpX/5/

**OVERVIEW**

I'm creating a tabbed website, using the jQuery `.animate` feature. Which on my live site seems a glitchy on the first alternation, but I can't seem to replicate it in the fiddle.

The left tab animates the `div#wrapper` right positioning to -170px and back to 0 - then i've added the `.removeAttr('style');` to remove the style attribute so it does not interfere with the right tab.

The right tab animates the `div#wrapper` left positioning to -170px and back to 0 - then i've added the `.removeAttr('style');` to remove the style attribute so it does not interfere with the left tab.

**PROBLEM**

The `.removeAttr('style');` is not removing the inline style attribute after `.animate` completes, which causes my left tab to be disfunctional if the right tab has been opened.

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/QyhpX/5/) http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/QyhpX/5/

*Also does anyone notice any glitching on the first tab open alternation? Left or Right? It seems to hang on first opening, then suddenly it snaps open, but closes fine smoothly and then re-opens smoothly. Its just the first click opening.*

**TAB CODE SCRIPT**

```
var $tabLeft    = $(".tab-left-button span"),
    $tabRight   = $(".tab-right-button span"),
    $siteSlide  = $("#wrapper");

    $tabLeft.on('click', function () {
        if ($tabLeft.html() == 'X' ) {

            $siteSlide.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);
            $tabLeft.html('Tab Left');

            return false;

            $siteSlide.removeAttr('style');

        } else {

            $siteSlide.stop().animate({ right: "-170px" }, 300);
            $tabLeft.html('X');
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);                             
        }
    });

    $tabRight.on('click', function () {
        if ($tabRight.html() == 'X' ) {

            $siteSlide.stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
            $tabRight.html('Tab Right');

            return false;

            $siteSlide.removeAttr('style');

        } else {

            $siteSlide.stop().animate({ left: "-170px" }, 300);
            $tabRight.html('X');
            $('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);                             
        }
    });
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/QyhpX/5/

Comment: Commenting just to say that I like those side menus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @JamesMcLaughlin correctly mentioned, you have a `return` statement before your `.removeAttr` call. That is what we call 'unreachable code'.

However, even if you would switch those statements, it'll still not work, because `.animate()` works asyncronously. That means, you need to call `.removeAttr` once the animation entirely finished, like so:

```
$siteSlide.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300, function _afterAnimation() {
    $siteSlide.removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're returning from the function first, so the line will never be executed. Change:

```
        return false;

        $siteSlide.removeAttr('style');
```

to

```
        $siteSlide.removeAttr('style');

        return false;
```

(and then go buy a nice JavaScript book).

Comment: You might also want to include that `return false` is discouraged since it breaks jQuery chaining. it's better to take the event as an function parameter and use `e.preventDefault()` (or buy a jquery book)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Simplybj/QyhpX/12/ is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but not exact, `animate()` was blocking `removeAttr()` from executing.  Simply adding a `stop()` to the chain will get `removeAttr()` working again:

```
$example.animate({
        opacity: "0",
    }, 700);
$example.stop().removeAttr("style");
```